# Error 500 on version 2.1.3

Tags: magento-2.1.3

Giving the whole backsotry.

I upĺoaded all files from version 2.1.3 using git to a remote Ubuntu server and I got the following error

```
Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory
```

I googled a bit and found this http://www.technetexperts.com/web/magento-2-installation-guide/

After that, it started appearing the error `pelago/emogrifier v0.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system`, which lead me to this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943762/composer-install-issues. I installed all extensions following these steps and the `magento-check.php` that I found somewhere.

After all that, I get error 500 on my home page and have no idea on how to proceed. Does anyone know what might be happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: Error 500 usually says you have problems with your web server configuration. Check Web server logs for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions in your Magento Install Directory:

*Use Magento in Ubuntu:*

```
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
sudo chown -R :www-data .
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

*Use Magento in Centos:*

```
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
sudo find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo chown -R :apache .
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

I'm using this [tutorial from Magento Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/legacy-file-system-perms.html).